# Yii2 Trying to get property 'course_name' of non-object

Tags: yii2

Всем привет!
Прошу помочь, начал работать с YII. Сайт готов, все нормально работало. После НГ начала вываливаться ошибка.

```
        'attribute'=>'course_id',
        'contentOptions'=>['class'=>'kv-align-middle'],
        'headerOptions'=>['class'=>'kv-align-center kv-align-middle kv-merged-header'],
        'value'=>function($model) {
            return $model->course->course_name;
        }
```

Никаких изменений на НГ не происходило, как я понял он не видит course_name, но не пойму почему...

Comment: потому что  course = null

Comment: берите в руки отладку и смотрите почему переменная null.... или если нахочется возиться, используйте null coalesce оператор

Comment: Спасибо!
return ($model->course) ? $model->course->course_name : '';

Comment: Вообще я имел в виду `return $model->course->course_name ?? '';`

Comment: А в php8 можно попробовать даже вот так: `return $model?->course?->course_name;`  или `return $model->course?->course_name;`  если модель всегда точно есть